# Make Flask pass "self" arguments to server functions?

Tags: python, python-3.x, flask

I have Flask server wrapped in a class that looks something like this:

```py
from flask import Flask, Response, render_template, request


class Server:
    def __init__(self, host, port):
        # Initialize Flask:
        self.app = Flask(__name__)
        self.host = host
        self.port = port
        self.string = "foobar"

    @staticmethod
    @app.route("/")
    def index():
        return render_template("index.html")

    @app.route("/pantilt")
    def not_staticmethod(self):
        return self.string

    def start(self):
        app.run(host=self.host, port=self.port)
```

The problem is that I have a function (`not_staticmethod`) that requires a `self` argument. Is there a way that I can make Flask always pass certain arguments to the functions?
i.e: Put a line in `__init__` that is something like `self.app.alway_pass_args = (self, other_arg)`

Comment: The flask documentation does have a section on [class-based views](https://flask.palletsprojects.com/en/2.3.x/views/).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I haven't personally used `Flask` but you should be able to simulate the decorator with something like this.

```
from flask import Flask, Response, render_template, request


class Server:
    def __init__(self, host, port):
        # Initialize Flask:
        self.app = Flask(__name__)
        self.host = host
        self.port = port
        self.string = "foobar"
        # just call self.app.route's returned callable
        # since that's what the decorator is doing anyway
        self.app.route("/pantilt")(self.not_staticmethod)
        self.app.route("/")(self.index)

    @staticmethod
    def index():
        return render_template("index.html")

    def not_staticmethod(self):
        return self.string

    def start(self):
        self.app.run(host=self.host, port=self.port)
```

Comment: You could also use `self.app.add_url_rule("/route", view_func=not_staticmethod)` per the Flask docs:
https://flask.palletsprojects.com/en/2.3.x/api/?highlight=add%20url%20rule#flask.Flask.add_url_rule

Comment: Yeah, that's all `app.route` [is doing anyway](https://github.com/pallets/flask/blob/57e926c7916ef5fd7d4abac965273ea185e497d2/src/flask/scaffold.py#L436). Not being familiar with `Flask`, I wasn't sure if that was exposed to the user or not.

Comment: Yeah, even though though that's what the flask docs say to use, app.route is more readable and familiar :)